# MySQL issues with where clause and bit field

Tags: mysql

I have a field in my table called isDeleted and its a bit(1)

I had a few items in that table where isDeleted was 1 and I need to change it to 0. When I update these items to 0 in PhpMySQL and run another query to get the items where isDeleted = 0 the items that were once marked as 1 and not appearing in this query. Here is the query in question

```
SELECT * FROM 'myTable' WHERE isDeleted = 0
```

no matter what I do to change these items from 1 to 0 they do not appear in the results for the query above....please help

Comment: How did you change `isDeleted` to 0

Comment: Try casting yout integer to bit  `SELECT * FROM 'myTable' WHERE isDeleted = (0 AS BIT)`

Comment: @Rik nice thought. I think casting is not needed. `create table test (id int, isdeleted bit); insert into test values (1, 0), (2, 1); select id from test where isdeleted = 0;` will output id=1. Maybe there's something else going on.

Comment: You have single quotes around the table name.  This is invalid syntax.

Comment: Is there error message after UPDATE?

Comment: See my test [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c54b4/1). [11.2.4 Bit-Value Type - BIT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/bit-type.html).

Answer (score 1):

AS @GordonLinoff comment already pointed you just need use backticks

```
`myTable`
```

for table and column names when needed instead of single quotes `'myTable'` which is in your query posted.

And you can simply check `WHERE isDeleted` vs `WHERE !isDeleted` for `BIT(1)` type.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b8ed4b/2

```
SELECT * 
FROM myTable
WHERE isDeleted;

SELECT * 
FROM myTable
WHERE !isDeleted;

SELECT * 
FROM myTable
WHERE isDeleted=0;
```